# Windows Phone 7 listbox colorize items?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to use the listbox with a htmlstring?

listbox.items.add(`"<font color='#efefef' size=2>asd</font>`");

?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. What is it that you want to do? Add a string containing HTML that'll be displayed according to the markup? Also, show an example that conveys your intent. There's nothing HTML about the string `"asd"`.

Comment: i d like to colorize my listbox items, and add a fontsize to it. in programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not natively. But you can do something like this:

```
listbox.Items.Add(new TextBlock()
{
    Text = "Asd",
    Foreground = Color.FromArgb(0xff, 0xef, 0xef, 0xef),
    FontSize = 2,
});
```